# Setup Github via "Titanium Studio" Terminal

Tags: git, github

I am trying to setup Github in my system via "Titanium Studio" terminal. I am doing with the help article in the following page http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/

When I enter these lines `$ ssh -T git@github.com` , Then the error message is coming like this

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number
```

Please help me.

Arun Krishnan

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: [git ssh problem bad file number - Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7145648/993555)