# git error: couldn't connect to host while accessing

Tags: git

Am getting the following error while trying to pull/push or create new-clone

error: couldn't connect to host while accessing https://github.com/user/pack.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed

when i googled, people suggested to setup http_proxy.. but i don't understand it
or i don't know to setup it.. am totally stuck up with it..

i don't know how to overcome these issues..

any help would be appreciated..

NB: note that i was able to use git before couple of days.. in the last couple of days it has been screwed up.. please help..

Comment: To help diagnose where exactly the issue is, can you create a brand new githib repository, clone it, make a change an d push and pull ok?

Comment: i can't even create a new clone, am facing the same issue when i tried to do a new clone.. seems some git settings is screwed up.. but don't know exactly..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a generic network or server issue that has nothing to do with git.

Comment: If everything is fine and configured as you said, then its may be a DNS cache issue that can be fixed by running this command 'ipconfig/flushdns' in your command prompt window, to clear DNS cache. I have fixed it this way.

Comment: I had the same problem with the clones from gitlab-ci runner on an old CentOS box. Upgrade ```nss curl libcurl```, solves the problem. Seems the same problem mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538130)

Answer (score 17):

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy 
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

works for me

Comment: Worked for me as well

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me on my Vagrant VirtualBox VM running Ubuntu 12.04. The vagrant instance had been up for several days. I restarted the VM (`vagrant reload`), ssh'd back in, and it worked.

What's the cause? Not sure. Someone else can speculate. However, I always like to [reboot three times](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8_Kfjo3VjU) just to be sure ;)

Answer (score 6):

I've faced the same error when I changed the network that my laptop was connected. Editing /etc/resolv.conf properly solved the problem:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Making resolv.conf blank and reboot might solve it too.

On debian 2.6.32-5-amd64 + VirtualBox 4.2.12.

Answer (score 3):

I gave the follwoing command to restart my network services. This would work for sure:

```
service network restart
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution, if this is a repository under you control, would be to use an [SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) for your repository access instead of HTTP. Update your remote accordingly by dropping the `origin` remote with:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin <ssh_path_from_github>
```

You can find the ssh path in github here:

[image: SSH github access]

Make sure to preface it with `ssh://` when you re-add the remote. If this doesn't work then we'll look at the http proxy settings, but based on your faux github link, I'm hoping it's a repository under your control.

Comment: I tried that as well... it failed at doing the ssh test, when i ran "ssh git@github.com", it said:
$ ssh git@github.com
ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 22: Bad file number

i tried these with the gitbash..

now i don't know how to proceed.. i googled and found some links but those didn't help either..

Comment: Sorry, said what? I think your copy/paste got munged.

Comment: when executed from Git-bash i got the following errors

Charles@HARD-FX /d/ror/Pack (master)
$ git pull
error: couldn't connect to host while accessing https://github.com/user/Pack.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed

$ ssh git@github.com
ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 22: Bad file number

Comment: Google suggested [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8019448/877115) for that ssh problem.

Comment: even tried doing that n i get the following message:

Charles@HARD-FX /d/ror/Pack (master)
$ ssh -vT github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Charles/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Connecting to ssh.github.com [207.97.227.248] port 443.
debug1: connect to address 207.97.227.248 port 443: Not owner
ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 443: Bad file number

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same error when wanted to push code on github. The problem was that I had messed up some environment variables on my Ubuntu machine. This happened because I wanted to use a manual proxy on google chrome.

If you are using linux use the following command to see if `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` are set to some ip address.

```
env | grep http_proxy
```

Then use the following commands to `unset` the value of these two variables.

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

Try to use git again. If it does not work then do a reboot. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My extremely simple solution was to first clone the empty new repo. I then deleted the .git folder in my project and moved all my project files & folders into the new repo folder. I then changed directories into that folder and then ran the `add`, `commit`, and `push` commands. Everything worked well.

Before trying this solution, I had not cloned the git repo first. My project folder and the repo had the same name, I had run `git init`, `add`, `commit`, and set the upstream, but `push` was giving me an error (failure to connect to host).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error in Visual Studio 2013:

```
An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error).
An error occurred while sending the request.
```

Then I tried using Git GUI:

```
Pushing to https://leniel@bitbucket.org/myrepo/bhp.git
error: Couldn't resolve host 'bitbucket.org' while accessing https://leniel@bitbucket.org/myrepo/bhp.git/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Guess what... my `Parallels Virtual Machine` had no internet connection at the moment. After reestablishing the internet connection I could push my commit. :) Can't believe that happened. We're so used to have an internet connection always on.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error when try to pull using different linux user.

```
ls -lah
whoami
```

Make sure current user is same as owner of that folder.