# Can't clone a github repo on Linux via HTTPS

Tags: linux, git, github

I'm trying to do a simple `git clone https://github.com/org/project.git` on a CentOS box but get:

> error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing
>   https://github.com/org/project.git/info/refs
>
> fatal: HTTP request failed

It never prompts me for my username/password, just fails.

I can make the exact same call on my Mac no problem- what am I missing?

Comment: Its a fresh wide open CentOS 6.3 box on the cloud- internet access not a problem

Comment: @Yarin: I trust you already read this : https://help.github.com/articles/https-cloning-errors The last resort would be to use ssh I think. Also, you might want to check the email your git is configured with... not sure if it helps but make sure it corresponds to the one you use with your github account.

Comment: yeah- none of those check out- literally copying a working command from my mac terminal into the linux terminal- no password prompt, just craps out

Answer (score 219, accepted):

The answer was simple but not obvious:

**Instead of:**

```
git clone https://github.com/org/project.git
```

**do:**

```
git clone https://username@github.com/org/project.git
```

**or (insecure)**

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/org/project.git
```

(Note that in the later case, your password will may be visible by other users on your machine by running `ps u -u $you` and will appear cleartext in your shell's history by default)

All 3 ways work on my Mac, but only the last 2 worked on the remote Linux box. (Thinking back on this, it's probably because I had a [global git username](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git) set up on my Mac, whereas on the remote box I did not? That might have been the case, but the lack of prompt for a username tripped me up... )

Haven't seen this documented anywhere, so here it is.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the `git config --global user.name` detail, that was it for me!

Comment: Note that as of git 1.7.10 you *will* be prompted for a username, [according to @JERC](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20646216/165673), so this should no longer be an issue..

Comment: I had the same issue (with GIT 1.7.1, CentOS5), but I couldn't add the username/pwd into the URL-s becouse I had to install bundles from private Bitbucket repos (and obviously I won't add username and pw info into a composer.json/composer.lock). Becouse GIT didn't allow me to type them manually, I had to go the hard way, and updated GIT with the help of the RPM Forge Repository (http://guru4hp.blogspot.hu/2012/08/how-to-configure-rpmforge-repository-on.html). I followed @muness' guide found here: http://serverfault.com/questions/448814/yum-doesnt-install-latest-version-of-git-on-centos6

Comment: This is the answer if you are using git  1.7.1 on linux

Comment: applicable if using anything prior to 1.7.10

Comment: I guess I didn't realize that "org" should be replaced by my oranization name. I really am a n00b. Once I did that, and of course put in my actual "username", I was prompted for my password and now I am rolling. By the way, I just installed git on CentOS and 1.7.1 is what they handed me.

Answer (score 34):

You can manual disable ssl verfiy, and try again. :)

```
git config --global http.sslverify false
```

Comment: For the BeagleBone Black with Angstrom, opkg doesn't supply the required version to do ssl verification so this is the only choice I've found to work.

Comment: @flickerfly statement is valid..no other way to clone using https except using this method when using beaglebone black with Angstrom OS.

Comment: Disabling ssl verification is a bit dangerous. A malicious man-in-the-middle could theoretically send you a modified git repo.

Comment: Also had to do this when using GitLab

Answer (score 13):

I met the same problem, the error message and OS info are as follows

OS info:

> CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
>
> Linux 192-168-30-213 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

error info:

> Initialized empty Git repository in /home/techops/pyenv/.git/
>   Password:
>   error:  while accessing https://waterdrops@github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git/info/refs
>
> fatal: HTTP request failed

git & curl version info

> git info :git version 1.7.1
>
> curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
>   Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp
>   Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz

debugging

> $ curl --verbose https://github.com
>
> - About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#0)
> - Trying 13.229.188.59... connected
> - Connected to github.com (13.229.188.59) port 443 (#0)
> - Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
> - CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
>     CApath: none
> - NSS error -12190
> - Error in TLS handshake, trying SSLv3...
>     GET / HTTP/1.1
>     User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
>     Host: github.com
>     Accept: */*
> - Connection died, retrying a fresh connect
> - Closing connection #0
> - Issue another request to this URL: 'https://github.com'
> - About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#0)
> - Trying 13.229.188.59... connected
> - Connected to github.com (13.229.188.59) port 443 (#0)
> - TLS disabled due to previous handshake failure
> - CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
>     CApath: none
> - NSS error -12286
> - Closing connection #0
> - SSL connect error
>     curl: (35) SSL connect error

after upgrading curl , libcurl and nss , git clone works fine again, so here it is. the update command is as follows

> sudo yum update -y nss curl libcurl

Comment: Thanks - this worked best for me on with bitbucket on a repo on a client's old CentOS 6.6 Server running git 1.7.1

Comment: I am having this problem with gitlab-ci runner. Work's fine after the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks a ton bro ... updating curl worked for me ...

Comment: This was the main problem the whole time. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 12):

Make sure you have git 1.7.10 or later, it now prompts for user/password correctly. (You can download the latest version [here](http://git-scm.com/downloads))

Comment: I had the same problem, My git Version was 1.7.1 when I upgrade to 1.7.10 now It prompts User/Password Correctly!!, (the version 1.7.1 IS NOT THE SAME TO 1.7.10) Please check the versions before to devoted.

Answer (score 10):

I had to specify user name to work on 1.7.1 git version:

```
git remote set-url origin https://username@github.com/org/project.git
```

Answer (score 6):

As JERC said, make sure you have an updated version of git. If you are only using the default settings, when you try to install git you will get version 1.7.1. Other than manually downloading and installing the latest version of get, you can also accomplish this by adding a new repository to yum.

From [tecadmin.net](http://tecadmin.net/how-to-upgrade-git-version-1-7-10-on-centos-6/):

Download and install the rpmforge repository:

```
# use this for 64-bit
rpm -i 'http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm'
# use this for 32-bit
rpm -i 'http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.i686.rpm'

# then run this in either case
rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
```

Then you need to enable the rpmforge-extras. Edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo` and change `enabled = 0` to `enabled = 1` under `[rpmforge-extras]`. The file looks like this:

```
### Name: RPMforge RPM Repository for RHEL 6 - dag
### URL: http://rpmforge.net/
[rpmforge]
name = RHEL $releasever - RPMforge.net - dag
baseurl = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/$basearch/rpmforge
mirrorlist = http://mirrorlist.repoforge.org/el6/mirrors-rpmforge
#mirrorlist = file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mirrors-rpmforge
enabled = 1
protect = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmforge-dag
gpgcheck = 1

[rpmforge-extras]
name = RHEL $releasever - RPMforge.net - extras
baseurl = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/$basearch/extras
mirrorlist = http://mirrorlist.repoforge.org/el6/mirrors-rpmforge-extras
#mirrorlist = file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mirrors-rpmforge-extras
enabled = 0 ####### CHANGE THIS LINE TO "enabled = 1" #############
protect = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmforge-dag
gpgcheck = 1

[rpmforge-testing]
name = RHEL $releasever - RPMforge.net - testing
baseurl = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el6/en/$basearch/testing
mirrorlist = http://mirrorlist.repoforge.org/el6/mirrors-rpmforge-testing
#mirrorlist = file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mirrors-rpmforge-testing
enabled = 0
protect = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmforge-dag
gpgcheck = 1
```

Once you've done this, then you can update git with

```
yum update git
```

I'm not sure why, but they then suggest disabling rpmforge-extras (change back to `enabled = 0`) and then running `yum clean all`.

Most likely you'll need to use `sudo` for these commands.

Comment: Really great answer! Solved my issues on Redhat (RHEL) 6.3.

Comment: Instead of manually editing the repo file twice (first enable extras and then disable it again), I just ran `yum install --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras git` and that dit it!

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get a git 1.7.1  to work after quite some time.

First, I had to do disable SSL just so I could pull:

```
git config --global http.sslverify false
```

Then I could clone

```
git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/PROJECTNAME.git
```

Then after adding and committing i was UNABLE to push back.
So i did

```
git remote -v

origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/PROJECTNAME.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/PROJECTNAME.git (push)
```

to see the pull and push adresses:

These must be modified with USERNAME@

```
git remote set-url origin https://USERNAME@github.com/USERNAME/PROJECTNAME.git
```

It will still prompt you for a password, which you could add with

```
USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.....
```

But dont do that, as you save your password in cleartext for easy theft.

I had to do this combination since I could not get SSH to work due to firewall limitations.

Answer (score 5):

This is the dumbest answer to this question, but [check the status of GitHub](https://status.github.com/). This one got me :)

Comment: Message from today: "We are still working to mitigate a very large DDoS attack. The site is now available for some users but we will remain in red status until we're confident the site is staying up."
Who hacks GitHub? Really?

Comment: obviously not homakov, he commits to master instead of DDoS

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and error. In my case it was the https_proxy not set.
Setting the https_proxy environment variable fixed the issue.

```
$ export https_proxy=https://<porxy_addres>:<proxy_port>
```

Example:

```
$ export https_proxy=https://my.proxy.company.com:8000
```

Hope this help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Every answer here predates 2021, yet there was a major change in 2021 on how https authentication works. In August 2021, Github removed support for using your account password from the cli. You can still use HTTPS, but you will need to set up a **Personal Access Token** to use instead of your password.

Git's cli is misleading when it prompts for your password. In fact, Git wants you to use a Personal Access Token (PAT) instead of your password. From the CLI, PAT substitutes the password wherein you enter the PAT instead of password when it prompts for password.

From the Github website, login and then:

1. Click on your Icon
2. Choose Settings
3. Go to Developer Settings
4. Click on Personal Access Tokens (it gives you a choice of
   Fine-grained tokens or Tokens classic)
5. Click Generate New Token (and specify access levels for the token)

Once the Token is created, log into your Linux server (e.g. RHEL8) and clone the repo without specifying username and password:

```
git clone https://github.com/org/repo-name.git
Username for …
Password for …
```

It then prompts for Username and Password. For Username, specify your github username which you use to sign into the website. For Password, specify the Token you created above. Then it will clone the repo successfully.