# http 401.1 error while performing a GIT clone from a Linux server

Tags: linux, git, authentication, tfs, tfs-web-access

I'm running TFS 2013 with a GIT team project. When I perform a `git clone`from one of the local Windows servers I don't have any issues:

```
-bash-4.1$ git clone "http://tfsadm:tfspas@tfs.server.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/Main"
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/tfsadm/Mainframe/.git/
```

but when I perform a `git clone` from Linux, I get the following error:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing http://tfsadm:tfspas@tfs.server.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/Mainframe/info/refs fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Answer (score 3):

> Error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing https://github.com/Joey-myproject/repo.git/info/refs fatal: HTTP request failed

is an often reoccuring error.

One of the reasons of this happening is because the client is not authorized to access to that resource.

A general solution is to check for the following:

1. Do you have a stable git version?
2. Is the remote correct configured?
3. If 2FA is enabled, if so provide an access token.
4. Double check your permissions(username/password in configs) perhaps also  try to use the format ' https://username@mydomain.org/project.git''
5. Try ssh instead of https

I am not sure, but have you already seen this link [Can't clone a github repo on Linux via HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538130)? 
It can give some extra information.