# Github cloning : 403 Forbidden access while accessing info/refs

Tags: git, github, http-status-code-403

I am cloning a private repo from into an AWS box to make it ready for production.

```
git clone https://github.com/org_name/project_name.git
```

It returns me this error:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/pgupta/project-annie/.git/
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/org_name/project_name.git.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: If you work with AWS through ssh, you need to provide your ssh private key. What OS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by cloning using SSH. Here are the steps: https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/

```
Generate ssh key pair using the instructions given above
copy the ssh url from github repo
git clone url
```

Alternatively, you might also find solution to your problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12538716/3413239

Answer (score -5):

I think it's just because you have an extra ".git" at the end of your url.

Comment: please improve this so you make it look like an answer instead a comment...