# Why can't gitlab-runner clone my project? (Incorrect hostname, failed to connect)

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I set-up a Gitlab server and need to run tests Windows using gitlab-runner.exe.

The gitlab-runner's executor is set to `shell`, the `config.toml` looks like

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "PC123"
  url = "http://1.2.3.4/ci"
  token = "cd2b093adc5ca09ea41ee4eadb0752"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.cache]
```

When the test is spawned on a commit it fails with

```
Cloning into 'C:/git/builds/ac70aeb9/0/test/myproject'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@localhost/test/boundaries.git/': Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

I suppose the problem is the hostname "localhost" in the URL, which refers to the machine gitlab-runner is on. When I set-up the server in the beginning I used 'localhost' as the servers hostname. This was probably not the best idea. :)

In the meantime I changed this "localgit", but the URL does not adjust, it still shows "localhost". (Server restarted, gitlab-runner servive restart).

Could it be that the server's hostname is stored somewhere in the original repo that I cloned when the hostname was still `localhost`? `.git/config` shows the correct IP:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://1.2.3.4/test/myproject.git
```

I found another question ([GitLab runner unable to clone repository via http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003101/gitlab-runner-unable-to-clone-repository-via-http)) that mentions a way to add other hosts to gitlab-runner's `config.toml`, like

```
[runners.docker]
    extra_hosts = ["ci.mygitlab:127.0.0.1"]
```

But I must use the `shell` executor, not docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-development-kit/blob/master/doc/howto/runner.md), the solution is to replace the entry `host: localhost` in the Gitlab config file `/home/git/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml` with the IP address of the host.

Before replacing:

```
  gitlab:
    ## Web server settings (note: host is the FQDN, do not include http://)
    host: localhost
```

After replacing:

```
  gitlab:
    ## Web server settings (note: host is the FQDN, do not include http://)
    host: 10.0.1.2
```

Comment: this is a solution for local git or anything personal sized but I have the issue accessing my corporate gitlab server, putting the IP is not a solution as we rely on DNS. any ID? I don't have the issue with a normal runner, only with my DinD runner. I just had to add the dns search param in the config.toml

Comment: Putting the hostname there instead of the IP also works.

Comment: I am using windows, where should I see this `/home/git/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml` ?in windows environment

Comment: Windows for the server or the gitlab-runner?

Answer (score 2):

## Omnibus package installation

If you've installed GitLab using the Omnibus package, you will need to ensure that `external_url` in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` is set to either the host machines hostname or IP address. Using `localhost` seems to cause a conflict that results in the error that you describe. Here's an example:

```
## Correct
external_url 'http://192.168.0.2:8080'
## -or-
## external_url 'http://myhostname.com

## Incorrect
external_url 'http://localhost:8080'
```

Once you've corrected the `external_url`, you'll need to reconfigure GitLab using the following command:

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Comment: `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` made my day! thanks