# unable to access gitlab-ci-token Failed to connect

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to do CI/CD with gitlab on my virtual box (Ubuntu 16.04) and getting following error:-

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.5.0 (80b03db9)
  on sr-runner 1d32ebc7
Using Docker executor with image node:carbon-alpine ...
Pulling docker image node:carbon-alpine ...
Using docker image sha256:e707e7ad71865cab957512e1fab31873b7996e239859d733470eb707c31dd37d for node:carbon-alpine ...
Running on runner-1d32ebc7-project-1-concurrent-0 via practice-VirtualBox...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 9618581 Removing yarn
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@localhost/personal/firstAngular.git/': Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Gitlab runner is running fine:

```
practice@practice-VirtualBox:~$ sudo service gitlab-runner status
● gitlab-runner.service - GitLab Runner
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-04-24 17:41:00 SAST; 3min 0s ago
 Main PID: 883 (gitlab-runner)
    Tasks: 9
   Memory: 24.6M
      CPU: 365ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/gitlab-runner.service
           └─883 /usr/bin/gitlab-runner run --working-directory /home/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog --u
```

Please advise what could be wrong here?

Comment: I can see you using VM. Did you make necessary changes to your hosts file?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47695126/why-cant-gitlab-runner-clone-my-project-incorrect-hostname-failed-to-connect