# Gitlab runner docker Could not resolve host

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Im using 2 containers on my Ubuntu OS: Gitlab-ce and gitlab-runner

Containers names are: `gitlab_gitlab_1` and `gitlab_gitlab-runner_1`

I access to my gitlab app via `gitlab.localhost.com:801`

I register successfully a runner with this command:

```sh
docker exec -it gitlab_gitlab-runner_1 gitlab-runner register --non-interactive --url http://gitlab_gitlab_1 --registration-token _wgMgEx3nBocYQtoi83c --executor docker --docker-image alpine:latest
```

Then, when I start the job, I got this error message:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.7.1 (b9bba623)
  on 589a617ee407 12ba77f7
Using Docker executor with image alpine:latest ...
Pulling docker image alpine:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:3fd9065eaf02feaf94d68376da52541925650b81698c53c6824d92ff63f98353 for alpine:latest ...
Running on runner-12ba77f7-project-1-concurrent-0 via 01196621a827...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/root/test'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gitlab.localhost.com/root/test.git/': Could not resolve host: gitlab.localhost.com
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

In both containers, I can access to the hostname `gitlab.localhost.com`.
I think the issue comes from the image alpine which can not resolve the host.

How can I fix that?

Thanks

**Edit 1**

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'gitlab.localhost.com'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://gitlab.localhost.com'
    ports:
      - '801:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '22:22'
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    networks:
      - 'default'

  gitlab-runner:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest'
    depends_on:
      - 'gitlab'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
    networks:
      - 'default'
    links:
      - 'gitlab:gitlab.localhost.com'

networks:
  default:
    driver: 'bridge'
```

**Edit 2**

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'gitlab.localhost.com'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://gitlab.localhost.com'
    ports:
      - '801:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '22:22'
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - 'gitlab.localhost.com'

  gitlab-runner:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest'
    depends_on:
      - 'gitlab'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
    networks:
      - 'default'

networks:
  default:
    driver: 'bridge'
```

Comment: have you tried to create a docker network for these containers so they can be linked together ?

Comment: Yes I also created a user defined network with the default bridge driver. So they are in the same network.

Comment: In this case you access it within docker using the service name which i assume it will be "gitlab" where you can access it like this: http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gitlab/root/test.git/, or you can define a network alias to it or using this too gitlab_gitlab_1

Comment: How can i specify this ? I already register the runner using the container name gitlab_gitlab_1, didnt work.

Comment: I have submitted my reply as an answer

Comment: Related to https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1846 ?

Comment: Thank, I post the fix to my issue thanks to the post you linked.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Thanks to Tarun Lalwan link and according to Joyce Babu post, there are an [undocumented option](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section) from the gitlab runner repos in the
`[runners.docker] section`

```
network_mode : Add container to a custom network
```

So I have to set this option with my network name in the `config.toml` like

```
[[runners]]
  ...
  [runners.docker]
    ...
    network_mode = "gitlab_default"
```

OR when create the runner from command line

```
docker exec -it gitlab_gitlab-runner_1 gitlab-runner register \
--non-interactive \
--url http://gitlab_gitlab_1 \
--registration-token _wgMgEx3nBocYQtoi83c \
--executor docker \
--docker-image alpine:latest \
--docker-network-mode gitlab_default
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I was trying to figure this out for 2 hours...

Comment: Thank you!  I also wanted to add that "gitlab_default" is specific to @fliim's docker-compose.yml.  Remember the network name is the name of the service plus the name given inside the docker-compose.yml.  For example, mine is "infrastructure" and the network is "backend", so that network_mode line is `network_mode = "infrastructure_backend"`.

Comment: Thank you. You can list your networks by using `docker network ls`

Comment: GOD BLESS YOU!! It's work!

Answer (score 31):

I know this thread is old, but I saw everywhere threads pointing to this one,
but did'nt solve for me.

I got the same error message :

fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab.maison.fr:82/angular/test1.git/': Could not resolve host: gitlab.maison.fr

Adding     **network_mode = "host"**     to  **config.toml**     solve the problem.

My config.toml below on my local private network :

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "mars"
  url = "http://gitlab.maison.fr:82/"
  token = "TCfHAheTUdWMU2-fFNxK"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    network_mode = "host"
```

Comment: The problem is that you will not be able to use docker services in your gitlab jobs.

Answer (score 8):

This is working for me without define network in docker compose. Just add a extra_hosts record in gitlab-runner config just likes we add A record in other OS.

> sudo vim /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml

```
  [runners.docker]
tls_verify = false
image = "alpine:latest"
privileged = false
disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
oom_kill_disable = false
disable_cache = false
volumes = ["/cache"]
shm_size = 0
extra_hosts = ["xxx.xxx.com.cn:192.168.10.110"]
```

[image: official instruction for this args]

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section

Comment: Thank you! I've spent days trying to fix this and this was the only one that worked. Must be a newer problem because all of the answers seem to be from ~2017

Answer (score 3):

In case this helps others looking for this..

Same problem but GitLab and GitLab Runner run on different machines in LAN. DNS is working and `ping gitlab` works, except inside dockers:

### Reproduce problem:

```
$ sudo docker run -it alpine ping gitlab
ping: bad address 'gitlab'
^C
```

But works with DNS given:

```
$ sudo docker run -it --dns=172.168.0.1 alpine ping gitlab
PING gitlab (172.168.0.5): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.168.0.5: seq=0 ttl=63 time=0.536 ms
^C
```

### Config actual LAN DNS for docker.

Edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json` on the GitLab Runner (file did not exist yet) with contents:

```
{
    "dns": ["172.168.0.1", "1.1.1.1"]
}
```

Test again, now OK:

```
$ sudo docker run -it --dns=172.168.0.1 alpine ping gitlab
PING gitlab (172.168.0.5): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.168.0.5: seq=0 ttl=63 time=0.455 ms
64 bytes from 172.168.0.5: seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.905 ms
^C
```

If this is not how its supposed to be done, i'd be happy to hear.
If this problem shouldnt aught to exist in the first place, i'd be happy to hear as well. I was surprised to not find much references online to this problem for GitLab Runner..

Answer (score 2):

For anyone trying to deploy a runner using a docker executor in a private network with its own dns setup (i.e. having their own dns server), I tried the above solution in specifying the docker network in `config.toml` and it didn't work. Even though I could resolve gitlab.com from the host and the runner container I kept getting the above mentioned error. So the job container couldn't resolve gitlab.com. In the end what worked for me:

```
[[runners]]
  ...
  [runners.docker]
    ...
    network_mode = "host"
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding `network_mode = "host"` to `config.toml` and it picks the network configurations given in `/etc/resolve.conf`

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you have defined a network already which means that both `gitlab` and `gitlab-runner` are in the same network. you can verify that by using `docker inspect`. so you need to remove `links` as you don't need it.

In order to set a network alias you need to change the network part at `gitlab` service to the following:

```
gitlab:
  ...
  networks:
    default:
      aliases:
        - gitlab.localhost.com
```

References:

- [Compose file version 3 reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases)

Comment: I update my docker-compose.yml file as you suggest, run `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up -d`. Nothing changed.
For remind, gitlab-runner container can access gitlab.localhost.com but not the job. I think its inside the alpine:latest container run by the runner that cant access to this hostname

Comment: you can verify that gitlab container has the alias. and also you can log into gitlab-runner container and try to run ping or wget or curl on each gitlab's alias you will find through docker inspect.

Comment: The alias work inside the gitlab-runner container, as I said. But not in the job run from gitlab.

Comment: the error you posted seems like a normal git clone $URL, can you do the same manually within the runner container ?

Comment: `git clone http://gitlab.localhost.com/root/test.git` works from the runner container

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem these days, after trying all the proposed solutions of the various threads, I solved it in the following way:

```
pkill docker
iptables -t nat -F
ifconfig docker0 down
service docker restart
```

thanks to [My docker container has no internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430371/my-docker-container-has-no-internet)

Answer (score 0):

Network-wise a container is like a separate server with it's own ip address, network routes and DNS resolution. The only exception is to run the container on the host network.

That said, you probably need to figure out how DNS resolution works for the host machine (maybe you added something to /etc/hosts?) and then do the same inside the container.

Or use the exception and run on the host network.

Answer (score 0):

i gat same problem, in my issue server proxy was open and just disable it.
#systemctl status firewalld
#systemctl stop firewalld