# Gitlab Runner is not able to resolve DNS of Gitlab Server

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci-runner, kaniko

I'm facing a pretty strange Problem.

First of all my setup:
I got a private Gitlab server which uses Gitlab CI Runners on Kubernetes to build Docker Images. For that purpose I use the Kaniko Image.
The Runners are provisioned by Gitlab itself with the built-in Kubernetes management. All that is running behind a PFSense server.

Now to my problem:
Sometimes the Kaniko Pods can't resolve the Hostname of the GitLab server.
This leads to failed git pull and so to a failed build.
I would rate the chance to fail by 60%, which is way too high for us.
After retrying the build a few times, it will run without any problem.

The Kubernetes Cluster running the Gitlab CI is setup on CentOS 7.
SELinux and FirewallD are disabled. All of the Hosts can resolve the GitLab Server. It is also not related to a specific Host Server, which is causing the problem. I have seen it fail on all of the 5 Servers including the Manager Server. Also I haven't seen this problem appear in other Pods. But the other Deployments in the cluster dont really do connections via DNS. I am sure that the Runner is able to access DNS at all, because it is pulling the Kaniko Image from gcr.io.

Has anyone ever seen this problem or knows a workaround?

- I have already tried spawning Pods that only do DNS requests to the Domain. I didn't see a single fail.
- Also I tried to Reboot the whole Cluster and Gitlab instance.
- I tried to do a static overwrite of the DNS route in PFSense. Still same problem.

Here is my CI config:

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - echo $REGISTRY_AUTH > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $REGISTRY_URL/$REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_JOB_ID
  only:
    - master
```

The following error happens:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/MYPROJECT/.git/
Fetching changes...
Created fresh repository.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@git.mydomain.com/MYPROJECT.git/': Could not resolve host: git.mydomain.com
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50325932/gitlab-runner-docker-could-not-resolve-host) will help?

Answer (score 5):

We had same issue for couple of days. We tried change CoreDNS config, move runners to different k8s cluster and so on. Finally today i checked my personal runner and found that i'm using different version. Runners in cluster had `gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v12.3.0`, when mine had `gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v12.0.1`. We added line

```
image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine-v12.1.0
```

in `values.yaml` and this solved problem for us

Comment: I can confirm I had the same issue, downgrading it to v12.1.0 solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Downgraded to v12.1.0 and same issue here :/

Answer (score 3):

There are a env for gitlab-runner that can solve this problem

```
- name: RUNNER_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT
  value: "exec command before git fetch ..."
```

for example:
edit `/etc/hosts`

```
echo '127.0.0.1 git.demo.xxxx' >> /etc/hosts
```

or edit `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' > /etc/resolv.conf
```

hope it works for you

Comment: My friend and I spent six days to find the way how to make gitlab kubernetes runner run. That was the only way to do it.