# gitlab-runner: Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have `gitlab` running on `docker` container.
Also, I have `gitlab-runner` installed on my Cenots7 machine. Runner configured use `docker` executor.

config.toml

```
concurrent = 1                                                                                                          
check_interval = 0                                                                                                      


[session_server]                                                                                                        
  session_timeout = 1800                                                                                                

[[runners]]                                                                                                             
  name = "test"                                                                                                         
  url = "http://localhost"                                                                                              
  token = "gQfiiD4PUyPs4TiXLX9-"                                                                                        
  executor = "docker"                                                                                                   
  log_level = "debug"                                                                                                   
  pre_clone_script = "ls -la"                                                                                           
  clone_url = "http://localhost/"                                                                                       
  [runners.docker]                                                                                                      
    tls_verify = false                                                                                                  
    image = "node"                                                                                       
    privileged = false                                                                                                  
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false                                                                                
    oom_kill_disable = false                                                                                            
    disable_cache = false                                                                                               
    volumes = ["/cache"]                                                                                                
    shm_size = 0                                                                                                        
    # network_mode = "gitlab_default"                                                                                   
    # pull_policy = "never"                                                                                            
  [runners.cache]                                                                                                       
    [runners.cache.s3]                                                                                                     
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

When runner take job it can`t clone repo and print error:

```
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/root/project'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@localhost/root/project.git/': Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
/bin/bash: line 64: cd: /builds/root/project: No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

---

also, I tried: `clone_url = "http://172.17.0.1"`, but get same error

ping from docker executor:

```
ping 172.17.0.1
PING 172.17.0.1 (172.17.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.158 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.090 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.084 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.087 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.087 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.109 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.089 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.088 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=10 ttl=64 time=0.098 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=11 ttl=64 time=0.088 m
```

Comment: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-runner-connection-refused-unable-to-access/17687/10 Have you try that?

Comment: [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1243929/failed-to-connect-to-127-0-0-1-port-80-connection-refused-in-gitlab-ci) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34003101/gitlab-runner-unable-to-clone-repository-via-http/35759913#35759913) are related questions on the same error message.