# maven:latest image from gitlab-runner with docker executer "Failed to connect to gitlab Connection refused" using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using the gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest docker image on a Mac to build some custom gitlab runner that will span a custom maven image. At the moment I am having an issue to setup the basic environment using docker compose

See my docker-compose.yml below.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        # external_url 'https://gitlab.example.com'
        # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
      - '8443:443'
      - '2022:22'
    volumes:
      - '${HOME}/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '${HOME}/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '${HOME}/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - 'gitlab.example.com'
  gitlab-runner:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest'
    hostname: 'runner.example.com'
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - '${HOME}/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
    depends_on:
      - gitlab
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
        - 'runner.example.com'
```

At the moment I can successfully register the runner in the gitlab server and make a merge request

To register the runner I use the command below from within a running docker gitlab-runner container.

```
#[host] docker exec -it <gitlab-runner container-id> bash
#[gitlab-runner] gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --url http://gitlab.example.com \
  --registration-token "xxxxxx" \
  --description "docker-maven-runner" \
  --tag-list "docker" \
  --run-untagged="true" \
  --executor "docker"\
  --docker-image "maven:latest"
```

But the pipeline always fails with the following error

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.10.2 (c5874a4b)
   on docker-maven-runner 7zhsdXRx
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:02
 Using Docker executor with image maven:latest ...
 Pulling docker image maven:latest ...
 Using docker image sha256:44e27997f4c0493779146fc89ab571f5f829ac6538d0d7d40cbe9fe2b36d4a60 for maven:latest ...
Preparing environment
00:02
 Running on runner-7zhsdxrx-project-2-concurrent-0 via runner.example.com...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
 Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
 Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/hramanmcg/sonar-java-test/.git/
 fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab.example.com/hramanmcg/sonar-java-test.git/': Failed to connect to gitlab.example.com port 80: Connection refused
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:02
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

**My guess is that I need some way to specify the network so when the runner span out the container it will be connected to the correct network, but I can't find how to do this**

Some debug info

```
#docker-compose ps

                 Name                               Command                  State                                     Ports
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sonar-assistant-docker_gitlab-runner_1   /usr/bin/dumb-init /entryp ...   Up
sonar-assistant-docker_gitlab_1          /assets/wrapper                  Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:2022->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp

#docker network ls
 NETWORK ID          NAME                              DRIVER              SCOPE
 2fb969181eb3        bridge                            bridge              local
 0f73fd4baa79        host                              host                local
 96216f1d093e        none                              null                local
 7b120474fd1b        sonar-assistant-docker_default    bridge              local
```

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question.
I found an option on the registration that set the docker network.
using `--docker-network-mode`.
I am not sure how to use it in interactive mode but in none interactive the following worked for me

```
#[host] docker exec -it <gitlab-runner container-id> bash
#[gitlab-runner] gitlab-runner unregister --all-runners
#[gitlab-runner] gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --url http://gitlab.example.com \
  --registration-token "xxxx" \
  --description "docker-maven-runner" \
  --executor "docker" \
  --docker-image "maven:latest" \
  --docker-network-mode sonar-assistant-docker_default
```

Using GitLab Community Edition 12.10.2 and Gitlab Runner 12.10.2 and Docker desktop 2.3.0

Comment: While running `docker network ls` I find the names `bridge`, `host` and `none`. Do you have a suggestion which to use for `--docker-network-mode` or is the `sonar-assistant-docker_default` a custom bridge you installed to "bridge" the docker runner network to the local host network?