# git gives error while cloning a Bitbucket repository

Tags: git

I created one remote repository in BitBucket. Then I pushed one existing repository to the remote one from Windows. It gave SSL certificate error and I set the SSL verify to false by running the command "git config --global http.sslVerify false ". Then I could able to push and it did not ask for Username and Password.

Now I am trying to clone the repository from Linux machine and Linux machine asked for password. I gave the password and pressed Enter.

Now the Linux machine gives error,

```
error:  while accessing https://jee@bitbucket.bmogc.net/scm/~jee/git_test_sshkey.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

But If I clone the repository from windows machine, It does not ask for password, and the clone was successful.

Could anyone please help to resolve this?

Thanks,
Jeeva

Comment: remove `/info/refs`. `.git` should end git url.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The error was solved by setting "verify SSL to false"

Answer (score 0):

I suspect having `/info/refs` in the path is part of the trouble.

side note:
It may help if you post the git command that you use, and not just the error.
Also you might want to be careful what information is shown in your question.

When you post your question it may be best to replace personal information with generic information.
For example, in the question and answers here they use generic words like **USERNAME** and **PROJECTNAME**
[Can't clone a github repo on Linux via HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538130/cant-clone-a-github-repo-on-linux-via-https)

Comment: This error is solved by setting  "verify SSL to false"