# Git - error: RPC failed; curl 56 The requested URL returned error: 401: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, github, error-handling

Cloning the repo from GIT giving the error : RPC failed; curl 56 The requested URL returned error: 401.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't clone a github repo on Linux via HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538130/cant-clone-a-github-repo-on-linux-via-https)

Answer (score 0):

Error 401 means that you are not authorized to thas content.

Maybe you was logged in when you copied the link and it's different from the link, when you are not logged in.

I think the link is wrong in some kind.