# Log in to Github via Fedora Server 37

Tags: linux, git, github, debian, fedora

I am using Mac OS as my main operating system. I installed fedora 37 server edition in a VMware workstation as part of my course in college. I am trying to customize my prompt using this repo https://github.com/andresgongora/synth-shell.

I have installed git already. I also have power line-fonts installed. The issue I am having comes with this command: git clone --recursive https://github.com/andresgongora/synth-shell.git

When typed and executed I get a prompt asking me for a GitHub username and password. I enter my credentials and I get an error stating "Authentication Failed for [https://github.com/andresgongora/synth-shell.git"](https://github.com/andresgongora/synth-shell.git%22) even though my credentials are correct.

I have tried putting my username and password (both combinations separately) and I get an event error. I configured a global username and that doesn't work either.

Am I supposed to log in to my GitHub before cloning this repo? Does anyone else experience this or have a workaround?

I have tried putting my username and password (both combinations separately) and I get an event error. I configured a global git username and that doesn't work either.

Sites used:
[Can't clone a github repo on Linux via HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538130/cant-clone-a-github-repo-on-linux-via-https)
https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/setting-your-username-in-git
https://documentation.red-gate.com/soco/troubleshooting/authentication-failed-when-cloning-from-github

Edit: I have also tried setting up a token to log in with. The only issue I am having is my linux distro does not support copy and paste so I am having to type everything out.  When the password prompt comes up everything is blank to hide your password so I can't even check for spelling errors.

Comment: All repositories starting with `https://github.com/andresgongora/synth-shell.git` are public, I cloned them without entering credentials.

Comment: @phd Not working on a fresh Fedora Server 37 install...

Comment: Any useful info from `git clone -v --recursive https://github.com/andresgongora/synth-shell.git`?  What is the output of `git config --list`?

Answer (score 0):

As of mid 2021, github the company is now enforcing git HTTPS [authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-authentication-to-github#authenticating-with-the-command-line) to use an access token rather than username+password. [See this stackoverflow answer for full information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68775982/4327053).

One way forward is to generate an SSH key, and [upload the public portion to github](https://github.com/settings/keys).

It warrants mentioning that this change is specific to Github Inc., the Microsoft subsidiary. There have not been any changes to `git`, the distributed version control system. Other, similar repository hosting services may not necessarily bar you from authenticating via username+password. Gitlab is one example.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my issue by using cockpit in my web browser. Doing this allowed my to copy and paste my information and everything worked first try.

Beginner problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).