# Bitbucket Git Remote HTTPS connection refused

Tags: git, https, repository, bitbucket

I am trying to pull from a remote repo using https -- I don't have the ability on the machine I am using to configure ssh. I have been stuck on this error for a while. At no point am I prompted to enter a password.

```
error: Failed connect to bitbucket.org:3128; Connection refused while 
accessing https://MYUSER@bitbucket.org/MYUSER/REPO.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Comment: Can you add some detail, what command are you using?

Comment: `git pull origin master`

Comment: Have you checked Google for `Bitbucket Git Remote HTTPS connection refused`? There seem to be some things worth trying there

Comment: Yeah I have been googling for a couple hours to no avail

Comment: Did you try the alternative server on port 443
 referenced in that Bitbucket forum thread?

Comment: I tried `git remote add origin https://MYUSER@bitbucket.org:443/MYUSER/REPO.git` but got the same error

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out once I realized that no one else was encountering this error on the port number I was seeing (3128). Turns out it was a local proxy setting. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29178349/4491164) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't have a local proxy set up this/similar error can still show up if your internet latency is a bit off and its also possible that bitbucket is throttling private unpaid repos. It looks like the timeout for connections is rather aggressive. You can get an error such as the one below for any remote branch operations.

> "Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Connection refused"

Unfortunately the solution is rather dumb....keep trying till it succeeds and it will it appears from my experience.

Answer (score -1):

Get the IP address of `bitbucket.org` from ping command in some other system. Then edit the /etc/hosts file with this IP.
This worked for me.