# SSH Access Blocked After Trying GitStack

Tags: ssh, firewall, msysgit, gitstack

I'm using msysgit (Git-1.7.11-preview20120710.exe). I tried [GitStack](http://gitstack.com/) on Win8, which is a git server, and after uninstalling it because it didn't work out, I got blocked from accesing port 22 anymore. Here's what msysgit throws at me every time I try to push/clone/etc.

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.7.11-preview20120710)
Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help ' to display help for specific commands.

Alain@ALAIN-PC /d/Sync/Web/Work/Current/10042012_Madmen
$ cd madmen-intellectuals/

Alain@ALAIN-PC /d/Sync/Web/Work/Current/10042012_Madmen/madmen-intellectuals (de
v)
$ git push -v
Pushing to git@barrelstrengthdesign.beanstalkapp.com:/madmen-intellectuals.git
ssh: connect to host barrelstrengthdesign.beanstalkapp.com port 22: Bad file num
ber
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Alain@ALAIN-PC /d/Sync/Web/Work/Current/10042012_Madmen/madmen-intellectuals (de
v)
$ ssh -Tv github.com
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 207.97.227.239 port 22: Attempt to connect timed out
without establishing a connection
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number
```

This wasn't happening before installing GitStack. And I really haven't done anything other than that in the middle. Any suggestions ?

**Notes:**

1. While installing GitStack, I didn't check "Install msysgit" option, because I already had it installed. But the application didn't work out of the box. I assume that's the reason. I uninstalled it inmediately after that.
2. I've rebooted and disabled my firewall several times. I checked with Nmap and says "filtered".
3. **I already saw [Git SSH error: "Connect to host: Bad file number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number), but this is not the solution I'm looking for.** I want to go back to the previous state without the error. Besides, I'm not only using github.
4. It worked before installing GitStack.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitStack does not support yet Windows 8 as this system is not released yet.
GitStack creates a restore point before its installation. You should try to revert your computer at a previous  state.
Make sure also to double check that your firewall does not block the port 22. GitStack does not use and modify the port 22.