# Connecting to github result in error

Tags: git, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git SSH error: “Connect to host: Bad file number”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number)

Hi this si the first time I am trying to use github so bare with me.What I want to add a project to github and connect that project to AppHarbor.

So far from what I understand in order to upload files to github I have to configure git on my local computer.

I have been following the following tutorial to configure an SSH key :

```
https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys
```

But at the end when I run this command:

ssh -T git@github.com

i get this:

ssh: connect to host github.com port 22:Bad file number

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: GitHub has good tutorials https://help.github.com/articles/error-bad-file-number

Comment: Please post a specific problem... You've obviously misentered something in your configuration. Go through [the tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) again and let us know *which* step you're having trouble with.

Comment: It sounds like the ssh port is being blocked by your firewall.  You might have better luck using https:// urls if that's the case.  Also, I usually like to verify that SSH is working by telnet'ing to the remote end.  In this case, `telnet github.com 22`, and I'd expect to see something like `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github8` as soon as it connects.

Answer (score -1):

You can't connect github via ssh. The SSH key is configured to use the git protocol to receive and send changes in a repository.

Create a new repository in github (https://github.com/new) and follow the site instructions.

Comment: Actually, part of the [instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) involve connecting to verify it works.

Comment: Verify if you can use port 22. Try to connect via ssh another computer.