# CruiseControl.Net Build Exception

Tags: git, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

Need help with the following exception we got from our build server. I built fine one minute then all of a sudden we got this exception message. We haven't changed anything on the build server but we have in fact pushed more code in via GIT to remove the Visual Studio line from the project files as we are using mono. Can't think of anything that is causing this. WE are using the CruiseControl.Net Contentiousness Integration server. Any help will be much appreciated.

ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: ssh: connect to host xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx port 22: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
. Process command: git fetch origin
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo processInfo)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Git.GitFetch(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Git.CreateUpateLocalRepository(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Git.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModificationsWithLogging(ISourceControl sc, IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModifications(ISourceControl sourceControl, IIntegrationResult lastBuild, IIntegrationResult thisBuild)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to revert the git to a previous working revision, and it built. Remade that change and pushed that back into production and it built fine. must of been something to do with the project files or something. It all worked fine and without anything changed it would all of a sudden just not work. So solve by reverting and redoing.

Answer (score 0):

ths problem is not really CCNet related.

Check out this question with the same error message:
[Git SSH error: "Connect to host: Bad file number"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number)

Do you tested to run the command by hand from the same working directory and user the CCNet Service runs on?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like error is occuring while trying to call the update or trying to get the modifications.

Can you please try to call the update manually from the build server and check whether you have enough permissions to call the update from build server.