# Trying to push to github getting error bad file number

Tags: git, github-for-windows

```
ssh: connect to host guthub.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I want to push my code to repository pySan on github.com

```
drwxr-xr-x   13 san      Administ     4096 Mar  9 10:58 .git
-rw-r--r--    1 san      Administ     4096 Mar  9 10:53 .swp
-rw-r--r--    1 san      Administ        0 Mar  8 21:27 __init__.py
-rwxr-xr-x    1 san      Administ     1143 Mar  8 20:19 show.py
```

Comment: How are you pushing? Can you tell us the full command?

Comment: sorry my bad forgot to paste: here it is, `git push -u pySan showEnVar`

Comment: mistyped `github.com` as `guthub.com` when `git remote add`, or SSH was blocked (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8019448/927587)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo with your remote set to guthub.com.  Try setting it again to use github.com -- it'll be something like this:

```
git remote set-url pySan https://github.com/<username here>/pySan.git
```

Comment: set-url helps , doesnt need specify url every time