# Heroku app cannot be pushed

Tags: django, git, heroku

I tried deploying my first heroku code, but when I run `git push heroku master`, i get an error as:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

`git remote -v` gives,

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:dry-stream-5959.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:dry-stream-5959.git (push)
```

what is the problem?why wont the code be deployed?

Comment: Doesn't look like you're pushing to heroku, git is complaining that the connection to `github.com` is timing out. I somewhat recall having that issue in the past, would you mind posting your `git status`?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: `git status` command gives: git status            
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find strange that a `git push heroku master` references "`github.com`".
If you have to push to heorku.com, try a:

```
git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:dry-stream-5959.git
```

Then repeat your `git push`.
If the problem persists, and ssh port is blocked, then followed the [aforementioned link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number/8019448#8019448), but replacing `github.com` by `heroku.com`.

Comment: Now again I get this error:    `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: Sorry I am completely new to this and so I do not know anything about this

Comment: @AswinMurugesh As mentioned in https://www.heroku.com/, did you create your repo on heroku side? `heroku create dry-stream-5959`: follow carefully https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git.

Comment: I already used `heroku create` and only then got this name. Now if I give this command, I get `name already taken`

Comment: @AswinMurugesh then modify the remote url in order to match the name of your heroku app on the server.

Comment: Ya I did that. I changed the App's name in heroku.com and then changed the remote URL too.

Answer (score 0):

SSH is probably blocked on port 22.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8019448/2698101), it might help you out.

Comment: I did everything according to that answer. `ssh -T github.com` worked fine. But this problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

It is usually usefull to make a:

```
ssh -vvv yourlogin@heroku
```

in order to dispay all the operations taking place during the ssh communication.

Various causes can be at the origin of these,

- from a $HOME not correctly defined (usual on Windows where the
  environment variable %HOME% isn't defined at all by default)
- to an IP conflict address (see this thread) for the SSH daemon.

See also answer:// [Unable to Git-push master to Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922210/unable-to-git-push-master-to-github/922461#922461)