# xargs: git : Bad file number

Tags: git, xargs

Anyone know what could cause this error?

I am trying to create a package on git using this command:

```
git diff -z --name-only --diff-filter=MAR 5e2a4b4 5261fe1 | xargs -s1000000 -0 git archive develop -o 'package.zip'
```

Comment: This might be related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number

Comment: I don't think its a connection problem. I can create a package when using different commit numbers.  There is a problem with the specific commits.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from getting the error on ssh, which you've already ruled out, it could also be that git archive can handle a limited number of argument on the command line.

You are already (suspiciously) limiting the total running length of the arguments with `-s`, and you indicated your command is working for some commits but not the others. You could investigate the difference further by setting `GIT_TRACE=1`.

Generally it is common to limit the number of arguments with `xargs -n` in addition to `-s` but beware as this will execute the command passed to xargs multiple times, when the number of arguments exceeds the `-n` threshold, and `git archive` doesn’t support appending to an archive. You will have to call a script instead, that can increment a running number for the zip archive suffix, rotate the zip filenames in some acceptable fashion, or explicitly merge the output zip files into a master zip file.

And if you are running on cygwin, `EBADF` can also imply that the permission to one of the files to be archived was denied by the underlying OS.