# Windows Firewall, Tinywall and GIT

Tags: git, windows-7, windows-firewall

Just finally updated to Win7 from XP.
I am using Windows Firewall with added Tinywall (gives more control)

But when I use Git Bash, the firewall blocks all commands.
If I disable the firewall then everything works OK

I cannot figure the proper exceptions to add to TinyWall whitelist.

I added the shell window as well as the git.exe for application exceptions but still no go.
These exceptions program paths I added:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\git-cheetah\..\bin\sh.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe
```

Example of error:

```
$ git pull
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get TinyWall to work with git over SSH, you must white-list:

```
sh.exe
git.exe
ssh.exe
```

To work with git over HTTPS, you need only whitelist:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core\git-remote-https.exe
```

or

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-remote-https.exe
```

Comment: If you see the error described in the OP using Atlassian's SourceTree, whitelist `C:\Program Files (x86)\Atlassian\SourceTree\tools\putty\plink.exe` as well, that solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 with TinyWall i had to add exception for:

`C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-credential-manager.exe`

in addition to:

`C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`

`C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe`

`C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-remote-https.exe`

Comment: This is basically the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24019816/3367799). Please don't repost answers.

Answer (score 0):

If [restarting your shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10932916/6309) on Widows (after setting the whitelist) doesn't work, a workaround would be to use the port 443 for your ssh git session.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8019448/6309), also detailed in GitHub "[using ssh over the https port](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port)".

Or you can try and switch to an [https url](https://help.github.com/articles/error-bad-file-number), if your server supports it.

Comment: no idea if the server supports https url (still not very familiar with git).  I was hoping to be able to unblock those ports somehow instead of a work around.

Comment: @Karen is that server a known git hosting repo service? (like GitHub or BitBucket). Or is it a private server?

Comment: VonC - private hosting