# How can I let Git push/pull through Windows 7 Firewall?

Tags: git, windows-7, firewall, windows-firewall

My firewall is configured to deny all inbound and outbound traffic unless a rule says otherwise.

[image: Firewall Profile Screenshot]

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965340/windows-firewall-tinywall-and-git) suggests making rules for `git.exe`, `sh.exe`, and `ssh.exe`. So I did. Even `bash.exe`.

[image: Firewall Rules Screenshot]

Still when I run `git pull` I see:

`fatal: unable to access 'https://joncom@bitbucket.org/joncom/my-repo.git/': Failed connect to bitbucket.org:443; No error`

If I allow outbound connections by default, everything works.

[image: Firewall Profile Screenshot]

What rule am I missing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I needed to add a rule for `git-remote-https.exe` because I'm authenticating via HTTPS, not SSH.

On new versions of git, this is located at: `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-remote-https.exe`.

Edit: In fact I disabled the rules for `git.exe`, `sh.exe`, `ssh.exe`, and `bash.exe`, and still everything works, so they seem unnecessary for my purposes.

Comment: I used the logging technique from here (https://serverfault.com/a/841940) to determine that indeed only git-remote-https.exe needs to be allowed (Outbound rule) in order to get https working on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

When using:

```
git submodule update
```

I had to allow $GIT_BASH_LOCATION/usr/bin/ssh.exe through the firewall. In almost all other cases it is not used.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but since I don't have a git-remote-https.exe I needed to open the Ports for git. You need to open the ones described in [this question here.](https://serverfault.com/questions/189070/what-firewall-ports-need-to-be-open-to-allow-access-to-external-git-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Git for Windows and Putty, you should allow plink.exe