# Gitlab push problems

Tags: git

I have difficult struggle with pushing my project to *GITLAB*. When I try to push over HTTP, I have

```
* The requested URL returned error: 502 Bad Gateway
* Closing connection 3
error: fRPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 502
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

When I try to push over SSH, I have

```
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144811/git-ssh-error-connect-to-host-bad-file-number